# How can i load data from an url on app start

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms i need to load data while app start . I know that  the code must be in `App.cs` page. I can load data on a button click, now i want to load the data while app start . what is the right solution for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use async/await, if you need the download to be completed and do something with your data while you're still on the OnStart method:

```
protected async override void OnStart()
{
    // Handle when your app starts

    //retrieve your data
    TypeOfDataObject dataObj = await GetMyData();

   // Do stuff with your data
}

private Task<TypeOfDataObject> GetMyData()
{
      //Get your data from URL
      return dataObj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to await the data and also make sure that you deal with not being able to get the data and give the user the chance to retry.

Here is how I've done this:

```
protected async override void OnStart ()
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
            _data = await GetData();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             var errorMessage = e.Message; // Todo: Use nicer error message
             await loadingPage.DisplayAlert ("Error", errorMessage, "RETRY");
        }
    } while (_data = null);

    // Do stuff with _data
}
```

You can see a full example of this working along with displaying a loading page in my [DDD North Agenda App Sample](https://github.com/NogginBox/NogginAgenda/blob/master/NogginAgenda/App.xaml.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Just start loading data in the constructor of your App.cs. You can do it on a background thread if needed.

```
Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Do stuff in here
            });
```

Use a ContinueWith to handle any exceptions.

**Update**

As per my comments below, I don't recommend this way, using the OnStart is a much better approach.

Add an Async in there and load that way. The constructor needs to return and return with 17 seconds in the case of iOS.

```
protected async override void OnStart()
{

}
```

Also, make sure you place a try/catch around all that code because there is no Task to return an exception.

Comment: thanks for replaying , is it good to adding inside
 'protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts

         //   maindata.Load_category();
        }' @Adam

Comment: yes, as @dsnunez pointed out below, you can put it in the OnStart as well, which thinking now, might be a much better place to put it rather than in the constructor as you can also use await if needed, where as it gets trickier if you are doing that in the constructor.

Comment: even though you can call an awaitable method from a constructor, you can not await it, as constructors can't have the "async" modifier

Comment: Well you can with a .Wait() used under strict conditions (e.g. no mixing await and Wait()) but generally its not a good idea.